# Apache Camel watch files inside subfolders

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to write a camel route for watching files inside subfolders:

File system structure:

- output

  - folder1

    - file1
  - folder2

    - file2
    - file3
  - folder3

    - file4
  - etc.

I tried this route:

```
public class SimpleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

 @Override
 public void configure() throws Exception {
     from("file:C:/inputFolder?noop=true").to("file:C:/outputFolder");
 }
}
```

But it only watch files inside output directory, and not inside subfolders.

How can I configure a route to watch inside all subfolders?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To also read sub-directories too, you have to add the parameter [`recursive=true`](https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/components/camel-file/src/main/docs/file-component.adoc):

```
public class SimpleRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {

    @Override
    public void configure() throws Exception {
        from("file:C:/inputFolder?noop=true&recursive=true").to("file:C:/outputFolder");
    }
}
```